# create custom links in OSX dock

Tags: terminal, applications, bash

I have a program that runs from the command line but not correctly from the icon in the applications menu. While I would like to figure that out, all I want right now is  way to create a link in the dock where I can click that link, and run the command that lauches the program correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I use the platypus tool/framework to roll scripts into apps all the time:

- http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus/

The code for it is available and it's a free download with a request to donate financial support if you can/care.